# jquery dialog box slideUp slideDown

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I would like to show a dialog box on the right side when we scroll to a certain level of the page and make it disappear when we go back.
The problem is that the box appears but disappears immediately.
I used slide up and slide down jquery to make appear and disappear the dialog box.
If you have a better solution I take it too.

here is the code
https://jsfiddle.net/m3gcscd7/

Thank you for your help

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /******************************
      BOTTOM SCROLL TOP BUTTON
   ******************************/

  // declare variable
  var scrollTop = $(".scrollTop");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // declare variable
    var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    // if user scrolls down - show scroll to top button
    if (topPos > 200) {
      $(scrollTop).css("opacity", "1");
   $(scrollTop).slideUp();

    } else {
      //$(scrollTop).css("opacity", "0");
   $(scrollTop).slideDown();
    }

  }); // scroll END

  


}); // ready() END
```

```css
.scrollTop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #BE3F48;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.scrollTop a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right">
    <h2 id="h1">
     HEADING 1
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
    <h2 id="h2">
     HEADING 2
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
    <h2 id="h3">
     HEADING 3
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
  <div id="stop" class="scrollTop">
  <form>
   First name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="firstname">
   <br>
   Last name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="lastname">
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In case any of the answers is the solution to your question, please mark them as accepted

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `.slideUp()` and effectively hiding your div just right after you made it visible

> .slideUp( [duration ] [, complete ] )
>
> Description: **Hide** the matched elements with a sliding motion.

See [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the use of **slide down** and **slide up** isn't the best approach because they are only sliding effects on the elements. If you want to control the visibility of it it's better to manipulate the visible property.

In order to do this in your case is to :

In the css:

Add the **display:none;**

```
.scrollTop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #BE3F48;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  display:none;
}
```

And in your .js instead of sliding it just show it

```
// if user scrolls down - show scroll to top button
if (topPos > 200) {
  $(scrollTop).css("opacity", "1");
    $(scrollTop).show("fast");
} else {
  //$(scrollTop).css("opacity", "0");
         $(scrollTop).hide("fast");
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /******************************
      BOTTOM SCROLL TOP BUTTON
   ******************************/

  // declare variable
  var scrollTop = $(".scrollTop");

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // declare variable
    var topPos = $(this).scrollTop();

    // if user scrolls down - show scroll to top button
    if (topPos > 200) {
      $(scrollTop).css("opacity", "1");
    $(scrollTop).show("fast");
    } else {
      //$(scrollTop).css("opacity", "0");
     $(scrollTop).hide("fast");
    }

  }); // scroll END

  


}); // ready() END
```

```css
.scrollTop {
  position: fixed;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background-color: #BE3F48;
  padding: 20px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
  display:none;
}

.scrollTop a {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="right">
    <h2 id="h1">
     HEADING 1
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
    <h2 id="h2">
     HEADING 2
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
    <h2 id="h3">
     HEADING 3
    </h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
   <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante
      sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor. Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat
      risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus, fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim
      massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet. Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
      Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget
      hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing. Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae
      nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce pellentesque velit nec blandit pharetra. Donec ornare, massa non congue fermentum, tellus turpis congue nisi, non
      pharetra nisi orci vel nisi. Nam sed vestibulum augue. Morbi vestibulum, ante sed interdum ultricies, risus nibh consequat tortor, non cursus ante justo in turpis. Sed nec diam ultrices, venenatis tortor at, eleifend tellus. Donec id ornare tortor.
      Cras rutrum vel tortor suscipit fermentum. Sed molestie neque ultrices, consequat risus id, suscipit enim. Duis arcu nibh, interdum nec est ut, gravida molestie urna. Integer quam ante, aliquet a pretium vitae, tempor vitae diam. Maecenas eros risus,
      fermentum vitae congue interdum, pulvinar non leo. Suspendisse sit amet dignissim massa, ac ullamcorper urna. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras tincidunt orci lorem, eget placerat dui consectetur vel. Donec convallis in dolor quis laoreet.
      Nunc quis fringilla tellus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nullam congue felis ut lectus porttitor faucibus. Curabitur vitae lorem vestibulum, blandit dui at, luctus justo. Morbi lectus eros, faucibus luctus feugiat
      commodo, lobortis sed nulla. Fusce et fermentum ante. Vivamus consequat varius sem, eget hendrerit lectus tempus ac. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras imperdiet elit id auctor tincidunt. Morbi eu leo eros. Etiam ultricies ornare adipiscing.
      Mauris interdum eleifend congue. Curabitur eu ante sed turpis fermentum iaculis sed vitae nibh. Duis sapien tellus, laoreet at dignissim non, congue id nisi.
    </p>
  </div>
  <footer></footer>
  <div  id="stop" class="scrollTop">
  <form>
   First name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="firstname">
   <br>
   Last name:<br>
   <input type="text" name="lastname">
 </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: I hope it helps :)

Comment: That's what I want to do but on your example the box arrives by the side.
I would like to show the box from below.

Comment: You can manage all the show sequence. Here is the documentation  http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: I added this code but it does not work.                                                                                  $(scrollTop).show("slow", {
  direction: "top"
   },2000);

  $(scrollTop).hide("slow", {
  direction: "bottom"
   },2000);

What can I do ?

Comment: I found a solution with your help.
I removed the opacity.
slide up works well but there is a small problem slidedown which does not work.
Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/7jh16kew/

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. :)